# Average dilemma for multiple cells containing texts

Tags: excel

Good morning all, 
guess I need to change the coffee recipe as I can't get a SIMPLE formula...

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
Bob       20
Mary      10
Mark      5
```

---

```
=Averageifs(A1:A4,"=Bob",B1:B4)
```

what if I want Bob and Mark? **

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` like below

`=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B4*(A1:A4={"Bob","Mark"}))/SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4={"Bob","Mark"}))`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your formula has the arguments in the wrong order. Correct would be `= AVERAGEIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,"= Bob")`. However, if you want to add another criterion to the `AVERAGEIFS` function, you should be aware that the criteria are combined with `AND` logic, i.e. function will search for cells that contain both Bob and Mark at the same time, so it will not work. For your example, the function might apply if you use <= and> =, but you cannot guarantee that it will work correctly with real data. Therefore, I recommend using a little more complicated `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A1:A3="Bob")+(A1:A3="Mark"))*(B1:B3)/SUM((A1:A3="Bob")+(A1:A3="Mark")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working but then google sheets was not...

=ArrayFormula(SUM(SUMIF($A$2:$A$35,{"Bob*","Mark*"},$B$2:$B$35))/SUM(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$35,{"Bob*","Mark*"})))

this is a solution I found and works great
Thank you all